# Keras load model take a lot of time to load checkpoints

Tags: python, keras

I am creating checkpoints, so I can resume training again.

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model.h5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
```

but when I tried to resume training, loading `model.h5` is very slow.

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('model.h5',custom_objects={'GroupNormalization' : GroupNormalization},compile=False)
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I am using ```Quadro GV100``` to load my attention layer and it takes about 6s to load the model when setting the compile attr to ```True```. How much time does it take you to load the model?

Comment: i waited around one hour, its a 300 mb file, but it did not load

Answer (score 0):

.h5 extension is the one of the fastest of loading any large files. There can be couple of points to note while loading weights

1. Are you using normal HDD?
2. Are you using GPU's?
3. If not GPU then loading into RAM then
4. Loading & unloading operation is CPU intensive work if older processor might take time to load

Comment: i am using colab, but i also have test on my local.
Yea, i am using GPU

Answer (score 0):

Save a model using `ModelCheckpoint` without `save_weights_only=True` will save the optimizer state as well. You probably notice that the saved file size is much bigger than files with just weight.

Bigger files are slower to load, especially with slow CPU. Colab use 1 core CPU on GPU instances so it really slow.

If you, for now only want to resume your training then use `save_weights_only=True` and on resuming, create model and use `model.load_weight` should be faster. But note that the optimizer will got reset.

Comment: he is already using ```save_weights_only=True```. He mentioned that in the question!

Comment: @houzayfarifai That's `save_best_only`, it's entirely different thing!!

Comment: There's no way `load_model`'s gonna work with only weights right?

Comment: can i resume training by `load_weight` ?

Comment: You can, you only really need weights. Having optimizer state is better if you use something like `adam` but it only makes first few iterations converge faster, not a needed.

Comment: BTW you need to `compile` the model, doesn't matter before or after `load_weights`.